# Java String to Date without timezone

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have date like string `200901`

On android device I convert it to date:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat CARD_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd", Locale.getDefault());
 public static Date toCardDateFormat(String date) {
        try {
            return CARD_DATE_FORMAT.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and I get date: `Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2020`

After that I pass this date to spring controller and in controllers method I have this date like: `Mon Aug 31 20:00:00 GMT+03:00 2020`

Comment: How do you pass the `date` back to the *Spring* controller?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated along with `Date`, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). BTW a `Date` doesn’t have a time zone. Cannot have.

Comment: The solid solution is to use `LocalDate` from `java.time`. It’s date without time of day and without time zone. No room for confusion. :-)

Comment: For earlier Android, you should be using the *ThreeTenABP* project that adapts the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. Never use the terribly troublesome legacy date-time classes first bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the date in the default timezone, which will depend on the timezone configured for the device, but it appears to be `GMT+7`

It looks like the server that's running Spring is in the `GMT+3` timezone, and when it prints dates in *its* default timezone, that's what it uses.

The actual instant represented by `2020-09-01T00:00:00+07:00` and `2020-08-31T20:00:00+03:00` are the same.

This whole query is a result of two different computers printing the *same instant* as a date formatted in their *local timezone*.